# Show that each function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ can be written as the sum of an affine function ($ax +b$) and another function

Tags: calculus

Show that each function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ can be written as the sum of an affine function ($ax +b$) and another function that vanishes at 1 and -1

I managed to find the value of a and b in function of f(1) and f(-1).
But I think I should find the expression of the other function $R(x)$ .

Comment: What do you mean by 'cancels in 1 and -1'?

Comment: What does "function that cancels in $1$ and $-1$" mean?  Does it simply mean that the value of the function is zero at those points?

Comment: Try $g(x) = f(x) - ({1 \over 2} (f(1)+f(-1))+{1 \over 2} (f(1)-f(-1)) x)$. Then $g(1) = g(-1) = 0$.

Comment: For future reference, it would be more idiomatic in English to say that the function "vanishes at 1 and -1" (assuming that you mean its value is 0 at those points).

Comment: @copper.hat yes that’s what I meant